# Is the certificate of this Windows EXE really invalid?

Tags: certificates

The file can be downloaded from: https://www.vpay.co.kr/eISP/install/VPWSSetup_C.exe This is some stupid "security" ActiveX control that Korean government mandates for web commerce. On Windows 11, the signature is valid, but on Windows 10, it says that the certificate is not valid for the purpose. I am not sure why it says so. Is the certificate really invalid for the purpose?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The signature is valid and certificate itself is valid.

The problem is that `DigiCert Trusted Root G4` root certificate is not pre-installed on Windows 10/Windows Server 2016 (although it is trusted and part of Trusted Root Program). And digital signature contains the chain which includes a cross-certificate issued by another DigiCert root:

[image]

And this cross-certificate doesn't include `Code Signing` usage in EKU extension, that's why you receive that error message. Code signing certificates uses strict EKU chain validation. Strict EKU validation requires that every certificate in chain is valid for requested usage (Code Signing, in given case). You can read about strict EKU validation in my blog post: [Constraining Extended Key Usages in Microsoft Windows](https://www.sysadmins.lv/blog-en/constraining-extended-key-usages-in-microsoft-windows.aspx).

Since chain contains all required certificates that allow certificate chaining engine to build the chain up to trusted root -- there is no reason for CCE to go to Microsoft Root Program certs (embedded in `crypt32.dll`) and look for updates. But once this root is reached by another signature or process, then `DigiCert Trusted Root G4` will get installed from `crypt32.dll` cache and signature chain will turn to valid.

As a practice test, navigate to [DigiCert root certificate list](https://www.digicert.com/kb/digicert-root-certificates.htm), download `DigiCert Trusted Root G4` certificate and simply open it. Close and re-validate the signature and you will find that everything is ok:

[image]

and the chain will be shortened to exclude cross-certificate:
[image]

HTH